# How richtexbox can append text async from event listener on winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to work with richtextbox asynchronously? For example, I have a class and an event that logs some kind of calculation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExampleProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //I subscribe to an event that often sends messages 
            //and I want to display
            var c = new Core();
            c.Notify += DisplayMessage;
            c.ExampleMethod();
        }

        private void DisplayMessage(object sender, LogEventArgs e)
        {    //When a event arrives, transfer to richTextBox1
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + e.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss "), Color.SlateGray);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Message, Color.Blue);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            
        }
    }

    class Core
    {
        public delegate void LogHandler(object sender, LogEventArgs e);
        public event LogHandler Notify;

        //
        public void ExampleMethod()
        {   
            //generate messages with a pause in a random value
            var rand = new Random();
            
            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {   var pause = rand.Next(50, 2000);
                Thread.Sleep(pause);
                Notify?.Invoke(this, new LogEventArgs($"logged {i} pause in miliseconds {pause}", DateTime.Now, MessageType.Notice));
            }
        }
    }   //The class in which log messages are placed
        class LogEventArgs
    {

        public string Message { get; }

        public DateTime Date { get; }
        public MessageType MessageType { get; }


        public LogEventArgs(string mes, DateTime date, MessageType messageType)
        {
            Message = mes;
            Date = date;
            MessageType = messageType;
        }
    }

    enum MessageType
    {
        Notice,
        Warning,
        Error,
    }
     //Extension method to set line colors in RichTextBox
    public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
    }


}
```

Tried options with backgroundworker, task , synchronization... and got no result. I'm surprised that WinForms have been around for many years and Microsoft hasn't added asynchronous actions to them, for example `AppendTextAsync()`. How can I force text to be added asynchronously to a richtextbox?

Comment: To what benefit?

Comment: @CaiusJard I am processing data, they are not large, there are 10-20k lines and if I display logs in richtextbox, then my application just hangs for 5-10 minutes

Comment: Are you saying that adding 20000 lines to a rich textbox takes 10 minutes to complete?

Comment: @CaiusJard much less information gets into the richtextbox, maybe 5k lines, but after the execution  ends, the program interface does not respond for 5-10 minutes. The total time it takes for processing is about 2 minutes. For some reason, it takes 2 GB of memory

Comment: Do you need the font formatting etc of an rtb or would a simple textbox/listbox suffice? Does the behavior change if you use a simpler control?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I color the text so that it would be convenient to read the logs, there is very simple formatting, only two colors. I also tried it without formatting, just text, there is no difference, for some reason the richtextbox devours a huge amount of resources

Comment: But, what happens if you use a textbox or a listbox?

Comment: @CaiusJard The situation is the same everywhere (textbox or a listbox). The text can be added several times per second and the user interface hangs. Found this `Application.DoEvents()` removes the hang, but I would like asynchronous

Comment: Just try the `richTextBox1.BeginInvoke()` Also think about aggregating the data for you don't right each entry but several at once.

Comment: @Rekshino `richTextBox1.BeginInvoke()` freez the UI completely and does not output anything to the textbox

Comment: Make may be `public delegate void LogHandler(object sender, List<LogEventArgs> listOfLogEntries);` and transfer an aggregated data.

Comment: I suppose you have just too many calls. Too frequently.

Comment: Can you put a complete code to reproduce? An entire small project/ complete Form1.cs we can paste over a new project, after adding eg a rich/textbox to the form?

Comment: @CaiusJard  I have a lot of code, so I created a clean project that simulates the actions that I perform (updated the question and uploaded to github https://github.com/kvadrakot/ExampleProject)

Comment: As you call `ExampleMethod()` on GUI thread, the `Thread.Sleep(pause);` will sleep the GUI thread. You don't leave `button1_Click` before `ExampleMethod()` has finished and so block an event handling of the form for a while. Implement loop in a separate thread.

Comment: @Rekshino There is no pause `Thread.Sleep(pause)`  in a real project. I do not know how to generate a data simulation, my messages in the logs can receive 100 to 3000 milliseconds.  It helps  `Application.DoEvents()` to add, but as I understand it, asynchrony is not about winforms

Comment: I have had bad experience with `Application.DoEvents()`. `new Thread(()=>{loop}).Start();`

Comment: "asynchrony is not about winforms" it's not correct you can go with `async await` by GUI event handlers. E.g. `private async void button1_Click(...`

Comment: After races and deadlock, the third most common threading bug is a *firehose bug*.  Happens when a producer thread generates data faster than a consumer thread can process it.  Very visible when the consumer is the UI thread of a Winforms app, it stops taking care of its normal duties (like painting and responding to user input), desperately  trying to keep up with the Begin/Invoke requests and not being able to catch up.  Needs to be fixed by invoking less frequently, 25 times per second is plenty fast enough to keep a human eye busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another textbox on your form

Paste this code over ther top of everything in your Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExampleProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var c = new Core();
            c.Notify += DisplayMessage;
            await c.ExampleMethod();
        }

        private void DisplayMessage(object sender, LogEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + e.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss "), Color.SlateGray);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Message, Color.Blue);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            
        }
    }

    class Core
    {
        public delegate void LogHandler(object sender, LogEventArgs e);
        public event LogHandler Notify;


        public async Task ExampleMethod()
        {
            var rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {   var pause = rand.Next(50, 200);
                await Task.Delay(pause);
                Notify?.Invoke(this, new LogEventArgs($"logged {i} pause in miliseconds {pause}", DateTime.Now, MessageType.Notice));
            }
        }
    }
        class LogEventArgs
    {

        public string Message { get; }

        public DateTime Date { get; }
        public MessageType MessageType { get; }


        public LogEventArgs(string mes, DateTime date, MessageType messageType)
        {
            Message = mes;
            Date = date;
            MessageType = messageType;
        }
    }

    enum MessageType
    {
        Notice,
        Warning,
        Error,
    }
    public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
    }


}
```

Run it, click the button, then carry on typing in the other textbox - it stays responsive etc.. I don't know how long you'll have to wait to see major slowdowns as the text in the RTB gets huge.. but really you should look at periodically clipping your log so you arent building up megabytes of text in the RTB

Async in winforms is not about getting the controls to update using some async fashion; control must only be accessed by the thread that created them so any interaction with a control we generally ask that thread to do it (but I suppose it's a matter of perspective: if a background thread is asking the UI thread to update a control then it's being done asyncronous to whatever work the background thread is doing) - make sure the access you do with them is quick, do your heavy lifting (API calls?) using async way and then Invoke to get your UI thread to update the controls.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In real code, I have several other synchronous methods wrepped in my `Task`. I thought that it was enough to wrap the top method in a `Task` and everything would work, but instead `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously`

Comment: It rather depends what they are, but that message doesn't come from using Task; it comes form marking a method with the `async` modifier and then not doing any `await` operations in the body of the method